# Set arbitrary breakpoint in debugger

Tags: perl, debugging, module, perl-module

I have been using the perl interactive debugger (basically `perl -d script`)
I have a script that has quite a lot of modules imported and I need to debug a problem.
What I do is start the debugger and go over lines, stepping into where necessary.
But this is tedious as I need to step into many lines of code and function calls.

Question: Let's say that after going over the lines of code I eventually step into function `A::B::C::foo()` of some module where is the problem I am debugging.
Is there a way to set a break point in that function in the beginning of the debugging session so that I jump there directly instead of going over the code line by line until I reach there?
I know that I can add a break point in the same file my debugger is currently but how can I add a breakpoint in a line that is outside of the debugger's scope at this point (to some arbitrary file/module that eventually the debugger would have reached)?

**Note:**
Just to clarify: It is not like `A::B::C::foo()` is in line X of the script. It is *eventually* called after going down the call chain of **a lot other** functions in many modules

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:No.My problem is that I suspect which function is called in my flow but the code is very generic and I am not sure and I don't know the parameters that are being passed as the code is quite complicated (at least for me)

Comment: You don't need to know the parameters being passed to the function, only the function name.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:But I need to run the function with valid values to figure out what exactly is happening.May be I am missing your point

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I need to run the function with valid values," but perhaps you want to only break when a certain condition is met, which you can do with `b subname condition`, e.g. `b A::B::C::foo $x > 42`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set a break point by defining file name and then line number

```
b YourModule.pm:line_number
```

where line number is inside the module function you want to break at.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a breakpoint to a subroutine with the documented `b sub` syntax. In this case, just use

```
b A::B::C::foo
c
```

Comment: What if that function is a class function?Does that make a difference?I.e. `$object->foo();`

Comment: @Jim, shouldn't make a difference. In Perl a method is pretty much just a function with the object as the first parameter. If you know that `$obj->foo()` calls `A::B::foo`, then it's the same as `A::B::foo($obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can even put a breakpoint on a sub that hasn't been loaded/defined yet using the `postpone` option:

```
b postpone Name::Of::Sub::Yet::To::Be::Created
```