# How to set a breakpoint inside a Perl module's function?

Tags: perl, debugging, package, breakpoints

According to my expectation and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26875706/6607497 the following should work, but did not:

```perl-debugger
### complex test program using Test::More
### ...
ok 5 - use Auth::KeyStore::SQLite;
### ...
### So the module has been loaded
  DB<9> b Auth::KeyStore::SQLite:827
Line 827 of 'Auth::KeyStore::SQLite' not breakable.
### OK, that would mean there is no valid instruction on that line, BUT:
  DB<10> l Auth::KeyStore::SQLite::get_key
Switching to file 'lib/Auth/KeyStore/SQLite.pm'.
818     {
819:        my ($self, $id, $PIN) = @_;
820:        my $key_struct = $self->get_keystruct($id, $PIN);
821:        my $result = defined $key_struct ? $key_struct->key_data() : undef;
822
823:        $self->add_error(EB_NOT_FOUND, "key data not found for $id")
824             unless (defined $result);
825:        print "XXX: get_key: ", $result->as_string(), "\n"
826             if (defined $result);
827:        return $result
828     }
  DB<11> b 827
  DB<12>
### So line 827 is actually breakable!
```

This is the current Perl of SLES 12 SP5 on x86-64 (`perl5 (revision 5 version 18 subversion 2)`, `perl-5.18.2-12.23.1.x86_64`).

Comment: See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtAGbUYTnR0

Answer (score 2):

There's no file named `Auth::KeyStore::SQLite`, thus the inability to create a breakpoint in that file.

The command should be

```
b lib/Auth/KeyStore/SQLite.pm:827
```

Comment: So you are saying *when listing* I have to use the module notation (with `::`), but *when setting a breakpoint* I must use the module's path, *even if the module has been loaded already*? A clear violation of the principle of least surprise IMHO.

Comment: No, you can pass a sub by name to `b` as well, just like you did to `l`. But you don't want to break on a sub.

Comment: So basically "Line 827 of 'Auth::KeyStore::SQLite' not breakable." actually says "nothing of  'Auth::KeyStore::SQLite' is breakable, as I don't know what that is"? Kind of confusing error message, as I thought the problem is the line, not the file/module specification.